# jQuery click event when an element is inside another element

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with the jQuery click event when an element is inside another element. The code I am using is similar to the following:

```
<div class="a" id="a">
  <a class="b" id="b"></a>
</div>

$(".a,.b").click(function() {
  var current_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
  alert(current_id);
  ...do something...
});
```

When I click on the  tag class="b" it returns the encapsulated class="a" id instead of the id of class="b". How do I code it so that when I click on class="a" or class="b" it returns the correct corresponding id value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to stop it from bubbling.

```
$(".a,.b").click(function() {
  var current_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
  alert(current_id);
  // ...do something...
  return false; // <-- stop propagation
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9njP/

EDIT: better way

```
$(".a,.b").click(function(event) {
  var current_id = event.target.id; 
  alert(current_id);
  // ...do something...
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xMGgA/1/

Comment: You should better use `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: @FelixKling in the question he wasn't using the event parameter. I just gave a working example with the least amount of changes. You are definitively correct though.

Comment: 'return false;' worked. Thank you. @FelixKling how would event.stopPropagation() work?

Comment: @Kevin: have a look at the second example in this answer... the difference is that `return false` also prevents the default action of the browser which is not necessarily desired. `stopPropagation` is more expressive as well.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [event target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target).  This is the element where the event originated:

```
$(".a").click(function(event) {
  var current_id = event.target.id;
  alert(current_id);
  ...do something...
});
```

Note that this is the same as `$(event.target).attr('id')`, but cleaner and faster, and that I've removed the reference to `.b` since all events fired on `.b` will be matched on `.a` anyway.

[See jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/y2hhT/1/)

Comment: @ManseUK That doesn't do anything because you haven't added `event` as a parameter.

Comment: But yes, @FloydThreepwood, it would fire twice. [The handler should only be on the parent element](http://jsfiddle.net/y2hhT/1/), although whether this is the correct solution would depend on the actual real-world situation.

Comment: @ManseUK Yes, but it's an unnecessary change, and a bad one unless it's necessary. My change is probably the nicest solution for the abstract case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create this type of event

```
$(document).on('click','#a>.b',function(){
   var current_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
   alert(current_id);
});
```